# Transform Android Activity Class to Android Fragment Class Code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here is the code that Im trying to `convert` my code from `activity` extended class to `fragment` but it seems like it is difficult.

May i ask assistance to someone?

**Activity Java Code**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FileComplaintActivity extends Activity {

    private Button buttonSubmit;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextComplaint;
    //private EditText editTextPlateNo;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    File pic;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextNo;
    private Button button1;

    private final static String PREFERENCE_USER = "user";

    private Spinner spinnerComplaintType;
    private Spinner spinnerVehicleType;
    private EditText editTextBodyNo;
    private EditText editTextPlateNo;
    private EditText editTextLocation;
    private EditText editTextDate;
    private EditText editTextComplaintDetails;

    private String username;
    private String complaintType;
    private String vehicletype;
    private String date;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;
    private ImageView imageViewPhotoReport;

    String imageString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buttonSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        username= getUsername();

        editTextBodyNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBodyNo);
        editTextPlateNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPlate);
        editTextLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);
        editTextDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        editTextComplaintDetails = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextComplaintDetails);


        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        spinnerComplaintType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerComplaintType);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterComplaint = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.complaintType, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinnerComplaintType.setAdapter(adapterComplaint);
        spinnerComplaintType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                complaintType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), complaintType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinnerVehicleType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerVehicleType);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterVehicle = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.vehicleType, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinnerVehicleType.setAdapter(adapterVehicle);
        spinnerVehicleType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vehicletype = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vehicletype, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        editTextDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(year)
        .append("-")
                .append(month + 1)
                .append("-").append(day));

        imageViewPhotoReport=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhotoReport);

    }
    public void buttonDateClicked(View view){
        showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog. 
            // set date picker for current date 
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date 
            editTextDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(year)
            .append("-")
                    .append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day)
                    );
           }
        };

    @SuppressLint("UnlocalizedSms")
    public void buttonClickSubmit(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
//      smsManager.sendTextMessage("+639177260573", null, "HAHAHAH", null, null);

        smsManager.sendTextMessage("+639178866281", null, "Name: "+editTextName.getText().toString()+" Plate No: "+ editTextPlateNo.getText().toString() + " Complaint: "+editTextComplaint.getText().toString(), null, null);
        //finishAffinity();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editTextNo.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private String getUsername() {
        SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_USER,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
         username = preference.getString("username", "");
        if (!username.isEmpty()) {
            return username;
        }
        return "";
    }
    public void buttonClickEmail(View view){
        String to = "olannataniel@yahoo.com";
          String subject = editTextName.getText().toString();
          String message = editTextComplaint.getText().toString();

          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        }
    public void buttonSendClick(View view){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           int yyyy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
           int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
           int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
           date = yyyy + "-" + (mm+1) + "-" + dd;
        SendComplaintTask task = new SendComplaintTask();
        try {
            String status = task.execute().get();
            Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class SendComplaintTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url_addComplaint);



    //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> pairList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaintType", complaintType));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehicleType", vehicletype));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bodyNo", editTextBodyNo
                    .getText().toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plateNo", editTextPlateNo
                    .getText().toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaintLocation", editTextLocation
                    .getText().toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaintDate", editTextDate
                    .getText().toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaintDetails", editTextComplaintDetails
                    .getText().toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaintImage", imageString));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateFiled", date.toString()));
            pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));


            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairList));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";
                String json = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    json += line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                }
                Log.i("asdf", json);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                return status;

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
    public void buttonTakePhoto(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                //2
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
                imageViewPhotoReport.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                imageViewPhotoReport.setVisibility(1);

                //3
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                //4 
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    //5
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes.toByteArray(), 
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST: " + imageString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editTextComplaintDetails.setText(imageString);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_report, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Here is my initial Fragment Code**

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {

        public WhatsHotFragment(){}

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: i see no fragment in your second link. pls post the code by editing your post. the relevant parts only. and fragment is hosted by a activity

Comment: I have fixed. it 'wrong' URL.

Comment: i see nothing wrong in the second link

Comment: @Raghunandan what i want to ask is that how can i implement initViews() function in Activity to Fragment?

Comment: override onActivityCreated and initialize views there.

Comment: @Raghunandan Don't you think that this's the purpose of onCreateView()?

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem sir will you help me?

Comment: You need to CREATE (load from XML) your view in onCreateView() method of your fragment. This method returns the view, and system inserts it to the appropriate place. Then you can SET UP the views and subviews in onViewCreated().
I suggest you to study fragments before you try to do this. Create an empty test project and play with fragments. Try out what's written in the documentation.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem you can do it onActivityCreated also using `getView`. what is wrong with that??. You can also initialize it `onCreateView`. Look at the fragment lifecycle in the docs

Comment: getView() returns the view you should have created in onCreateView(). onActivityCreated() was designed to do something else. I'm not saying it's not possible, but it's not the logical way to do it. It's usually better to use things in the standard way. Don't you think?

Comment: Thank you sir. Currently im trying to transfer my spinners and buttons from activity to fragment.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem so what is the problem in initializing in `onActivityCreated` and what do you mean by logical? And what is onActivityCreated designed to do?

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem for info check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Yes, I see. Docs say that: "onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.
onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate()."
The link you're showing says that "retrieving views". I think this's not the same as creating views. Otherwise why would be there an onCreateView() method which passes a LayoutInflater to us in addition?

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem did i say its the same. secondly there is no harm in initializaing views in `onActivtiyCreated`. thirdly re-read my comments. If you have better solution go ahead and post one instead of commenting. If there is anything wrong in my post then you specify the same to correct the mistake.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I didn't say your post is wrong. I wanted to say that it's probably better to create the view in onViewCreated() and retrieve&setup the subviews in onViewCreated(), because it conforms to the documentation better.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem instead of commenting this go ahead and post it in your post. why inform me about it. I know this already. you can also specify that it conforms to the documentation better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
what i want to ask is that how can i implement initViews() function in Activity to Fragment
```

So

```
Buttom button
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Override `onActivityCreated`

Then

```
  button = (Button)getView()findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
  // similarly for other views
```

There is no harm in initializing view in `onActivitedCreated`.

You can also initialize your view's in `onCreateView`

```
Buttom button
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);
    button = button = (Button)getView()findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    // similarly for other views 
    return rootView;
}
```

For more info

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Can we move into stackoverflow chat to ask further questions?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie my lappy is running on low battery. so make it quick

Comment: Will you invite me to a chat?
Where to put the Override of onActivityCreated?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie in your fragment of course. you want to chat you invite me

Comment: I see. Thank you. Im not yet allowed to start a chat.

Comment: not yet sir. i dont understand it. sorry.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie post the updated code. code pls no links

Comment: I havent touch anything in the code. I was trying to seek help to the others. i will post it

Comment: @AndroidNewbie you have not tried but you need help sorry but that is not the way it works here on SO.

Comment: currently i am trying to work on with the spinners in fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Fragment lifecycle is a bit different than Activity lifecycle.
Although a fragment has the `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` etc. methods which are called along with the same method of the activity, we set up a fragment differently.

A fragment inflates its user interface in its `onCreateView()` method, which returns a `View`.
After that, we do further setup in `onViewCreated()`. (E.g. set up onClickListeners, etc.).

Of course you can find this all here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

**Edit:**
Although it's possible to setup subviews in onActivityCreated(), it's better to do the setup in onViewCreated(), because onViewCreated() was intended to do this, so it conforms better to the docs.

Comment: so it may result in smoother user experience. How to you say that it gives smoother user experience. If you have a listfragment then it is better to initialize listview in `onActivityCreated`. Check for content view not created on SO.

Comment: You may be right, those microseconds probably don't matter.